# Python: encoding in Sqlite query

Tags: python, string, sqlite, quoting

I have a problem with encoding in SQLite (`sqlite3` module in Python 2.7).
I have a table with two columns: (text_number int, word text).
In `word` we have numbers, English and Russian words.

I need to find all strings in table where word = search_word.

When search_word is number, I have no problems:

```
search_word = '146'
lenta_u_w = c.execute('SELECT * FROM lenta WHERE word = ' + search_word)
for w in lenta_u_w :
    print w
```

and gives something like `(361, u'146')`.

But, any other kind of characters do not work:

```
search_word = u'android'
lenta_u_w = c.execute('SELECT * FROM lenta WHERE word = ' + search_word)
for w in lenta_u_w :
    print w
>>>lenta_u_w = c.execute('SELECT * FROM lenta WHERE word = ' + search_word)
OperationalError: no such column: android
```

I try many versions of decode and so on, but nothing can help me.

Comment: Are you using the sqlite3 package?

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters when constructing and executing your queries, which will do the appropriate quoting and escaping for you:

```py
c.execute('SELECT * FROM lenta WHERE word = ?', (search_word,))
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) for the `Cursor` class in the sqlite3 package for more details.